# Raspberry PI2 what is the maximum sdcard speed?

Tags: sd-card, benchmarking, pi-2

The first Raspberry PI could not utilize more speed than approximately a class 6 card.

Can the new Raspberry PI2 utilize faster cards like class 10?
Or is the IO speed the same towards the sd cards as the first PI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SD card interface is unchanged.

See [Raspberry Pi 2 - FAQ and collated answers](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=683295#p683295)

Comment: The referred to "Raspberry Pi 2 - FAQ and collated answers" does not give answer to the question: "Raspberry PI2 what is the maximum sdcard speed?".